# Odoo 9 ValueError: External ID not found in the system:

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

I am at this for hours and can not figure it out. I am trying to print a form from a module I created. I keep getting the below error when I click the print button.

```
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: ch08.qweb_ds_repair_template
```

**My report.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

    <openerp>
        <data>

             <template id="qweb_ds_repair_template">
            <t t-call="report.html_container" >
                <t t-foreach ="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call ="report.external_layout">
                        <div class="page" >
                            <div class="oe_structure" />
                            <h1>Repair Form</h1>
                            <h2>Test: <span t-field="o.password"/></h2>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>

             <report id="report_ds_repair_template"
                     name="ch08.qweb_ds_repair_template"
                     model="ds.repair"
                     string="Repair Form"
                     report_type="qweb-pdf"

                     />

 </data>
    </openerp>
```

My module folder is called ds_repair. Not sure if I an missing a dependency in my **openerp**.py so here it is below

```
{
    'name': 'Repairs',
    'version': '1.0',
    'sequence': 200,
    'category': 'Manufacturing',
    'summary': 'Repair',
    'description': """,
The aim is to have a complete module to manage all products repairs.
====================================================================


""",
    'depends': ['base'],
    'website': '',
    'data': ['report/report.xml',
             'model_view.xml',

             ],
    'demo': [],

    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your module folder name is "**ds_repair**" so you should write **name="ds_repair.qweb_ds_repair_template"**

```
<report id="report_ds_repair_template"
                     name="ds_repair.qweb_ds_repair_template"
                     model="ds.repair"
                     string="Repair Form"
                     report_type="qweb-pdf"

                     />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities when you want to reference another xml_id.

You write:

```
<template inherited="module_name.xml_id">
```

This method's generally used when you want to reference an id in another module

Or you can

```
<template inherited="xml_id">
```

In this case, you would like to reference an id in the current module where your code is written.

The origin of your error can be:

1. You don't have a module named ch08
2. You have a module named ch08 but you haven't an id "qweb_ds_repair_template" in the module

But I think in your current situation you just would like to reference the id write above.

You can write

```
<report id="report_ds_repair_template"
        name="module_name.qweb_ds_repair_template"
        model="ds.repair"
        string="Repair Form"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"/>
```

PS : When I say module_name, it's the name of your folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think the ch08 in place of ds_repair is causing the issue.
I am pretty sure text preceding the dot is reserved for the namespace or addon ( addon folder ) name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

        <report id="report_ds_repair_template"
                 name="ds_repair.qweb_ds_repair_template"
                 model="ds.repair"
                 string="Repair Form"
                 report_type="qweb-pdf"/>

         <template id="qweb_ds_repair_template">
            <t t-call="report.html_container" >
                <t t-foreach ="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call ="report.external_layout">
                        <div class="page" >
                            <div class="oe_structure" />
                            <h1>Repair Form</h1>
                            <h2>Test: <span t-field="o.password"/></h2>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
         </template>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case odoo11, after searching many pages, Just look at the tutorial and it works:

> Finally restart Odoo and update the module’s data (to install the template) by going to Settings ‣ Modules ‣ Modules ‣ Academy and clicking Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to configure an existing Odoo 9 project. But, when I clone the module in the **custom_folder**. I named it **'odoo_xyz'**, however in the **openerp**.py, it was written **'xyz'**. So I renamed my cloned module to 'xyz', restart Odoo 9 and then create a new database. So, that it maintains a new reference system.